# Getting the type of the default case in pattern maching

Tags: scala, functional-programming, pattern-matching

I want to know the type of the object in pattern matching when the default case is triggered.

This is what I've tried:

```
    byeBuffer = array(0) match {
      case _: Int =>
        ByteBuffer.allocate(4 * array.length)

      case _: Long =>
        ByteBuffer.allocate(8 * array.length)

      case _: Float =>
        ByteBuffer.allocate(4 * array.length)

      case _: Double =>
        ByteBuffer.allocate(8 * array.length)

      case _: Boolean =>
        ByteBuffer.allocate(1 * array.length)

      case _ => throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Type not supported: " + _.getClass())
    }
```

But it says "Cannot resolve symbol getClass".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In this context, `_` means, that no identifier would be assigned to a matched value.

You can replace `_` with any identifier without type and it will still match remaining cases:

```
byeBuffer = array(0) match {
  case _: Int =>
    ByteBuffer.allocate(4 * array.length)

  case _: Long =>
    ByteBuffer.allocate(8 * array.length)

  case _: Float =>
    ByteBuffer.allocate(4 * array.length)

  case _: Double =>
    ByteBuffer.allocate(8 * array.length)

  case _: Boolean =>
    ByteBuffer.allocate(1 * array.length)

  case default => throw new UnsupportedOperationException(s"Type not supported: ${default.getClass()}")
}
```

Answer (score 3):

There is a common miss-understanding of how underscores work in

```
case _ => throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Type not supported: " + _.getClass())
```

The two underscores do not correspond to each other, instead it is expanded to something like

```
case _ => throw new UnsupportedOperationException(x => ("Type not supported: " + x.getClass()))
```

that is the second underscore is treated as anonymous function placeholder syntax and its scope is the first enclosing parentheses.